# Dismissing already shown Location & Region based Notifications in iOS

Tags: swift, notifications, geolocation, uikit, core-location

I currently have this code for adding/removing notifications when entering/exiting a region:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
  if region is CLCircularRegion {
    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.alertBody = region.identifier
    notification.soundName = "Default"
    UIApplication.shared.presentLocalNotificationNow(notification)
  }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion) {
   if region is CLCircularRegion {
    UIApplication.shared.cancelAllLocalNotifications()
  }
}
```

However the second part doesn't seem to remove already-displayed notifications from the user's phone. Is this possible?